# Configuring Kubernetes Service as a UPnP Device

Tags: kubernetes, upnp, weave

### Problem

I have set up a two-node [bare-metal kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/) cluster configured with [weavenet](https://www.weave.works/) and [metallb](https://github.com/google/metallb). I would like services hosted on this cluster to discover and interact with UPnP devices on my home network. I believe that for this to work, the UPnP discovery packets need to be configured to be re-multicasted to my home network. What is the right way to configure re-multicasting between a virtual weavenet network and a local network?

### My network

1. My home network is on `192.168.1.0/24`, with both the master and slave node.
2. Kubernetes deploys pods using the default weavenet setup which places all nodes somewhere in the `10.32.0.1/12` overlay network.
3. I have the ability to deploy services with a metallb LoadBalancer that will provide a LoadBalancer IP somewhere within `192.168.2.192/26`.

### What I've tried

I can execute a [test discovery script](https://github.com/rileymcdowell/k8s-deployments/blob/terrarium/terrarium/test-scripts/discover_as_host.py) that discovers my UPnP devices using multicast (`239.255.255.250:1900`) from any computer on my home network. Once I deploy to the cluster ([like this](https://gist.github.com/rileymcdowell/b26ba8aba5791beb90163784c48c7e98)), the UPnP devices are no longer detected. I can see the UPnP packets from other pods in the cluster, but not from my computers directly connected to my home network.

I believe the solution to this problem will involve re-broadcasting the UPnP packets from weavenet to my home network and reverse-proxying the responses... but I don't know how to do something like that with weave net. How can I configure any kind of service/deployment/pod/network that will interact with my UPnP devices the way [my test script](https://github.com/rileymcdowell/k8s-deployments/blob/terrarium/terrarium/test-scripts/discover_as_host.py) does when using the host's network?

Comment: Could you share the configuration of Pods or Deployments and Services related to them? Also, Could you share the scripts you are using for multicast requests?

Comment: @ArtemGolenyaev I added links to both the suggested scripts. I also confirmed that UPnP is working _inside_ the cluster, but the packets are stopping between weavenet and my home network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem**:
The uPnP UDP broadcast's are coming from the pod's internal address are being dropped by the node before it egresses into your home network.

i.e. packet would look like
`IP 10.32.0.x.45196 > 239.255.255.250.1900: UDP, length 215`

According to the docs at https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/services/source-ip/

type: LoadBalancer - will automatically source NAT to the **node** IP.

type: NodePort - will automatically source NAT to the node **pod** IP.

Using a **NodePort** with **hostNetwork** will bind the pod's NodePort to the Node IP, thus UDP broadcast will come from a legal address.

Limitations to this setup:

- Only one instance of your uPnP pod can be running at a time. Assuming a home network this will suffice. This is due to the direct mapping to the host network.
- NodePorts can only expose unprivileged ports in the 30000 - 32767 range.

**Solution**:

See terrarium-service-udp.yaml for NodePort allocation.

See terrarium-deployment.yaml for hostNetwork declaration.

terrarium-service-udp.yaml:

```
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    metallb.universe.tf/allow-shared-ip: terrarium
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: terrarium
  name: terrarium-udp
spec:
  ports:
  - name: '32767'
    port: 32767
    protocol: UDP
    targetPort: 54321
  - name: '31900'
    port: 31900
    protocol: UDP
    targetPort: 1900
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: terrarium
  type: NodePort
```

terrarium-deployment.yaml:

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: terrarium
  name: terrarium
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: terrarium
    spec:
      hostNetwork: true
      containers:
      - image: docker.lan/terrarium
        name: terrarium
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        - containerPort: 32767
          protocol: UDP
        - containerPort: 1900
          protocol: UDP
        resources: {}
      restartPolicy: Always
```

I have a working configuration for minidlna. If you need it for comparison, let me know and I will upload to GitHub.

Comment: I am interested by your minidlna configuration. Let me know if you can share it.

Comment: hostNetwork: true + Service worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: Confirmed that this approach is valid with UDP broadcasting in general from within a Kubernetes container, in microk8s.